# Как выстроить блоки в 2 ряда? Flexbox

Tags: html, css3, flexbox

Нужно выстроить блоки в 2 ряда, при этом так, чтобы каждый из них был шириной 25% от ширины экрана, и высота динамически изменялась с шириной (что бы при любом разрешении получался квадрат).

При уменьшении экрана, допустим доходя до 700px, эти 8 блоков должны выстроиться в 4 ряда по 2 блока. Искал инфу в гугле, не нашёл (либо нашел, но в виду своей неопытности не знаю как приспособить под себя).

```css
.our-projects {
  width: 100%;
  height: 699px;
}

.wrap-projects {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: #cec;
}

.projects-items {
  display: flex;
  width: 1365px;
  min-width: 1365px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 599px;
  background: #cee;
}

.proj-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fef;
}
```

```html
<section class="our-projects">
  <div class="wrap-projects">
    <div class="projects-items">
      <div class="proj-item">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/img-proj1.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-item">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/img-proj2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-item">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/img-proj3.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-item">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/img-proj4.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-item">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/img-proj5.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-item">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/img-proj6.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-item">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/img-proj7.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-item">
        <a href="#"><img src="../images/img-proj8.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-projects" style="display:flex;height:100px;width:inherit;background-color: #ce2;">

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper, .other {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block div {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #ff9700;
}

.other {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="other">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.b-col {
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
}

.b-item {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .b-col {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="b-row">
  <div class="b-col">
    <div class="b-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-col">
    <div class="b-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-col">
    <div class="b-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-col">
    <div class="b-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-col">
    <div class="b-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-col">
    <div class="b-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-col">
    <div class="b-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-col">
    <div class="b-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```